# Connecting Raspberry Pi to SFM3520-OP fingerprint module

Tags: uart, raspberry-pi-desktop

I want to connect an [SFM3520-OP fingerprint module](http://www.fingerprint-it.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/SFM-Catalog.pdf) with the RS232C serial port to the Raspberry Pi UART but I am doubtful about their logic level. Should I use a Max2323 or does it not need it?

Answer (score 2):

The Pi's UART is 3V3 (0-3V3) only.  If you connect anything outside that range you will probably destroy the UART and the Pi.

Comment: so what is the solution, friend? with which IC should I convert it to the RS232C(5 volt) level?